# fubar'd a ruby installation on ubuntu, need helping purging it for reinstall

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i originally followed these steps to get a RoR environmentgoing: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

that worked. then i put 1.9.2 on here. then i decided i want the original setup, did a "whereis ruby" and deleted those directories manually.

that fubar'd my ruby installation. i can't use the repository to what i originally had. how can i purge ruby from completely and start fresh?

right now the specific error is this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:11:in `require': no such file to load -- thread (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:11
        from /usr/bin/gem1.8:8:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/gem1.8:8
tipu@tipu_ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825057/how-to-completely-wipe-rubygems-along-with-rails-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving enough real information to be specific, but this is what I'd try:

1. Use apt-search to locate Ruby 1.8.7 for your OS version.
2. Using apt-get, uninstall that version so you're back to what APT thinks is a clean slate.
3. Again using apt-get, reinstall that version so you're back to what APT thinks is a normal installation.

From that point, I would STOP messing with the system Ruby, and instead use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage and install any new Ruby and gems installations into RVM's `~/.rvm` sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the Tin Man's answer:

I wrote [a guide to installing Ruby and Rails on Ubuntu](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you) which you may find useful for getting this all peachy again.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall libruby1.8. I'm pretty sure that will take care of it. I had exactly the same problem.

Comment: Worked for me ! "aptitude reinstall libruby1.8" fixed this error, thanks !